# Using JavaScript in params attribute in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails, parameters

I hope that someone can assist.

I have following code which is not accepted:

```
<g:link title="Periodendaten speichern" action="speicherePeriodendaten" params="'\'pStart=\' + $('#periodeStart'${i}').value'" id="${zwzPeriode.id}">
```

With $('#periodeStartX'), I am trying to get the DOM element with the ID periodeStartX, where X is the current value of i. i is coming from a g:each-Tag (status=i)

I know that following is working:

```
<g:link title="Periodendaten speichern" action="speicherePeriodendaten" params="'\'pStart=\' + this.value'" id="${zwzPeriode.id}">
```

But in the above scenario, I don't want to have the value of the current Tag, I want the value of another Tag.

My problem is therefore, that I don't understand how to escape here correctly.

I would appreciate any good hint.

Best Regards,
Michael

Comment: are you sure that `params="'\'pStart=\' + this.value'"` is working? what do you get on client side for such code?

Comment: Not any more... At least in a g:link. I have seen that I have used it this way in g:remoteFunction-Tag and g:link is ignoring params attribute? At least in Firebug I cannot see that params is used. And furthermore, g:link is evaluated once when response is generated, so I think have to combine here again g:link with g:remoteFunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach below:

```
<r:require module="jquery"/>

<input id="periodeStart1" value="V1" />
<input id="periodeStart2" value="V2" />

<%-- Sample variables --%>
<g:set var="i" value="1" />
<g:set var="id" value="42" />               

<%-- Resolve pStart "onclick" event --%>                
<a href="${createLink(action: 'speicherePeriodendaten', params: [id: zwzPeriode.id])}" onclick="this.href=this.href+'?pStart='+$('#periodeStart${i}').val()">Sample Link</a>
```

Edit1: Also, you should probably wrap $('#periodeStart${i}').val() with encodeURIComponent(). Just in case.

Comment: This looks good, changing the href when click event happens. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the $ sign as Groovy will try to treat it as an expressions:

```
<g:link title="Periodendaten speichern" action="speicherePeriodendaten" params="'\'pStart=\' + \$('#periodeStart'${i}').value'" id="${zwzPeriode.id}">
```

Comment: This I have tried, but what I have learned now is that params is evaluated at the response generation and not at the time where user clicks on the link. So the javascript can never run at the time where user clicks on it. So, I think g:link is not usable here at all.